# Force of Friction and Drag together

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, drag

Q :  A car is accelerating to the right from a stop. Identify all forces and draw a free body diagram. It is required to use both "Force of friction on car" and "Drag".

I am addressing this comment suggested by the system - "ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort "

The specific question regarding physics is "When is there both a force of friction and drag on a car, if it was in air, I know that only drag exists"
As for the effort, that drawing is mine, of course I have used a tool to draw it and have researched the matter in our book.

A : After reading through the book, the normal force and weight are opposite to each other and equal. Here is my direction for force of friction and Drag.
F - Force of Friction
D - Drag
n - Normal Force
w - Weight.
Please verify if my directions of Drag and Friction force are correct based on car accelerating to the right.

[image: Friction Force and Drag]

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Sorry "check my work" questions are *off topic* for this site.

Comment: Friction and drag oppose motion.  Why are they opposite?  In fact, they are the same

Comment: Sir, Thank you let me make them the same direction and check. I was confused about that concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both friction and drag oppose motion.  Drag is essentially the air resistance force, which is the frictional force between the air and the car.  Hence, both the frictional force and drag arrows should point left.  In addition, your free body diagram is wrong.  The car is not a point mass.  You should just draw a rough sketch of a car.  This can allow you to better indicate frictional force, which occurs between the wheel and the ground.

Comment: Drag includes more than just "frictional force between the air and the car". It covers also the inertial resistance of air molecules when being pushed away as well as the "suction" due to a lower pressure forming behind the falling object. Equating drag with air friction is a tad too simplistic in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Both the drag and friction will be opposite to the motion of car as they are non conservative forces they will slow down the motion of car and the Motion will cease after some time.

Comment: This is more suited for a comment